# Using SED or AWK to separate .csv column data using a delimiter

Tags: csv, awk, sed, delimiter

I'm working with a large data containing seven columns.

Columns 2-7 contain data that is prepended with the column header name + "=". For example column 2 contains this data:

```
Row 1: Date=2017-08-19
Row 2: Date=2017-08-19
Row 3: Date=2017-08-19
Row 4: Date=2017-08-19
```

For example column 3 contains the following data:

```
Row 1: Campaign=123456789
Row 2: Campaign=123456789
Row 3: Campaign=123456789
Row 4: Campaign=123456789
```

I need to remove the prepended data (all of which uses the string + "=" format) so that every cell only contains the actual data. How can I do this using SED or AWK and most importantly how can I export that data into a new file that contains the naked data (Non prepended data)? Thank you.

```
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-18 00:10:26.39242  Campaign_ID=123456789   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-18 00:27:38.416628 Campaign_ID=123456790   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-28 07:35:48.400623 Campaign_ID=123456791   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-14 09:34:12.602475 Campaign_ID=123456792   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-21 13:27:01.466864 Campaign_ID=123456793   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-12 16:42:07.427034 Campaign_ID=123456794   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-19 20:31:09.754326 Campaign_ID=123456795   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-30 14:32:28.054    Campaign_ID=123456796   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-09 12:08:31.876589 Campaign_ID=123456797   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
11111111-1111-1111-111111111111 Date=2017-08-21 22:03:17.1221   Campaign_ID=123456798   placement_name=HELLO    event_type=Impressions  pcp=NA  package_name=WORLD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sed** solution:

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]=]*=//g' file > newfile
```

Comment: Hey, so the solution you provided worked somewhat. It removed the prepended string + "=" from the columns, however it removed all the data from columns 3-6. Additionally, it outputted the data into a single column, meaning it combined the data from column 2 and column 7 in a single cell for each row of data.

Comment: @pghInitechBranch, instead of tailing the details of your local results - update your question posting all actual columns. (i.e. post the actual data)

Comment: Updated with csv example.

Comment: @pghInitechBranch, works fine for your posted input. See the screenshot https://ibb.co/mV9wi6

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why I had a different output the first time I ran that command. As I mentioned before, the output is still grouped together in a single cell. How do I get it so that each value (Date, Campaign_ID, Placement, etc.) is placed in its own cell?

Comment: @pghInitechBranch, perhaps, you are on Windows or MacOS system, not Linux, right?

Comment: Correct, I'm using MacOS.

Comment: @pghInitechBranch, try to add `-e` option. `sed -e 's/[^[:space:]=]*=//g' file`